# Wireless & Wired Connection Not Working after upgrade

Tags: 11.04, wireless, broadcom

My Lenovo Ideapad s10-3s refuses to connect to anything.

It recognises my wireless card (Broadcomm 4313) but whenever I boot up it shows "Wireless is disabled" under Wireless when I click on the Network icon even after I check Enable Wireless. After I reinstalled the Broadcom driver via Additional Drivers, it now has Enable Wireless greyed out and says "Wireless is disabled by hardware switch" (the hardware switch is on).

I have plugged in my ethernet cable directly but nm-tool says Connecting (configuring IP address) and then it becomes disconnected.

After I run `sudo rfkill unblock all`, under Wireless, it says "Device not ready".

What should I do?

```
ifconfig:
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:de:f1:0f:fc:ae  
          inet addr:10.164.12.120  Bcast:10.164.13.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f2de:f1ff:fe0f:fcae/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4651 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2791 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4280041 (4.2 MB)  TX bytes:323924 (323.9 KB)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:206 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:206 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:14936 (14.9 KB)  TX bytes:14936 (14.9 KB)
```

Was able to connect via ethernet on a friend's modem but Wireless remains at "Device not ready"

Answer (score 1):

1. If you have a wireless switch which you can toggle using your keyboard or in the BIOS, check if that's turned on.
2. try doing an `ifconfig` on the gnome-terminal and see if you are getting any io address there.  if there is, eth0 or wlan0 will show any ip address other than starting with 169. Also do a ping to check the response. An ifconfig output will be something like the one below:

.

```
ifconfig   
      eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 84:2b:2k:43:ef:08
      inet addr:10.11.23.80  Bcast:10.20.43.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe90::832b:2bff:feb5:ef08/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:26968 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:18958 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:19431851 (19.4 MB)  TX bytes:3558720 (3.5 MB)
      Interrupt:21 Memory:f7be0000-f7c00000
```

1. If you do get any connection then try this. open `/etc/network/interfaces` and comment out anything present there.

   gksudo gedit /etc/network/interface

Restart your computer after the changes and see if you get any connection.

Comment: no io address from ifconfig. /etc/network/interfaces/ : `auto lo iface lo inet loopback`

Comment: comment out everything in there and restart your system. lets see what happens then.